# Using VB.NET 2010, How do I rotate the elements in an array?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

For instance my array is {4,6,9,3,1}

And I want to cycle it X amount of times, for example 3 times,

I want my array to become {3,1,4,6,9}

Is there an easy way to do this in VB.NET?

Thank you

```
Function CycleArray(ByVal Arr() As Integer)
    Dim Tmp As Integer = Arr(0)
    Dim Arr2 = Arr.Skip(1).ToArray()
    Arr2(UBound(Arr2) + 1) = Tmp
    Return Arr2
End Function
```

Comment: So it's just an array of int? Write a method that does it longhand. There are other ways, but that's the easiest, and there's no need to get more sophisticated unless there's something you've not told us.

Comment: Increment an index into the array by the rotation amount and use the MOD operator to access to the elements.

Comment: I wrote a function to do it, but I can't test it yet:
    Function CycleArray(ByVal Arr() As Integer)
        Dim Tmp As Integer = Arr(0)
        Dim Arr2 = Arr.Skip(1).ToArray()
        Arr2(UBound(Arr2) + 1) = Tmp
        Return Arr2
    End Function

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to shift array elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/765863/how-to-shift-array-elements)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/765863/how-to-shift-array-elements

Answer (score 1):

You will find that using List is far easier than using Arrays in most cases.  To try this call the function like this:

```
    Dim MyArray() As Integer = {4, 6, 9, 3, 1}
    MyArray = LeftRotateArray(MyArray, 3)
```

the function looks like this:

```
Private Function LeftRotateArray(theArray() As Integer, Shift As Integer) As Integer()
    Dim shiftVal As Integer = Shift Mod theArray.Length 'in case Shift is larger than array
    Dim rv As List(Of Integer) = theArray.ToList
    For ct As Integer = 1 To shiftVal
        rv.Add(rv(0))
        rv.RemoveAt(0)
    Next
    Return rv.ToArray
End Function
```

The method is straight forward. Copy the array to a list and then move elements from the front to the rear until you have completed the desired iterations.  The return creates an array from the list.

or using this method from Jon Bentley's 'Programming Pearls':

```
Private Function LeftRotateArray(theArray() As Integer, Shift As Integer) As Integer()
    Dim shiftVal As Integer = Shift Mod theArray.Length 'in case Shift is larger than array
    Dim rv(theArray.GetUpperBound(0)) As Integer
    Array.Copy(theArray, rv, theArray.Length)
    Array.Reverse(rv, 0, shiftVal)
    Array.Reverse(rv, shiftVal, rv.Length - shiftVal)
    Array.Reverse(rv, 0, rv.Length)
    Return rv
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's essentially cutting and pasting a part of the original array at a specific place it can be done in one action. As dbasnett said it's easier to work with a `List` or `IEnumerable`, if you're focusing on clarity of code. Performance wise other solutions might be better.

```
    Dim numbers = New Integer() {4, 6, 9, 3, 1}
    Dim result = RotateRight(numbers, 3)
```

```
Public Function RotateRight(numbers As Integer(), offset As Integer) As Integer()
    Dim list = numbers.ToList()

    Return list.Skip(offset).Concat(list.Take(offset)).ToArray()
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply do `Array.Copy`. You would need to do it in two parts...

```
Function CycleArray(Arr() As Integer, cycleTimes As Integer) As Integer()
    Dim Arr2() As Integer
    ReDim Arr2(Arr.Length - 1)
    cycleTimes = cycleTimes Mod Arr.Length
    Array.Copy(Arr, cycleTimes, Arr2, 0, Arr.Length - cycleTimes)
    Array.Copy(Arr, 0, Arr2, Arr.Length - cycleTimes, cycleTimes)
    Return Arr2
End Function
```